# Creating folder tree with absolute directories > 256 characters?

Tags: vba, windows-7, excel

I have an Excel VBA macro that creates a folder tree based on an excel file.

My current issue is that I seem to get an error every time the absolute directory gets very long.

The program will throw run time error 76 (path not found).  I have a feeling that this is because the script references an absolute path that exceeds 256 characters.

Is there any work-around for this?  Or is my only option to shorten the folder names and thus the absolute path string?

***EDIT***

The code I'm using is the following:

```
Dim asheet As Range, r As Range, c As Range
Dim fPath As String, tmp As String

Set asheet = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

For Each r In asheet.Rows
    fPath = DEST_FOLDER
    For Each c In r.Cells
        tmp = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(tmp) = 0 Then
            Exit For
        Else
            tmp = Clean(tmp)
            fPath = fPath & tmp & "\"
            If Len(Dir(fPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir fPath
        End If
    Next c
Next r
```

Clean() is a self-defined function that will simply remove special characters from the string, i.e. !, #, _, @, $, &, *, ^,  and %.

Is there another method I could use to create these folders that perhaps would use a relative path instead of an absolute one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The windows API has a [limit of 260 characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#maxpath) (C:\ + 256 characters + ) in some circumstances. If you refer to your previous question, have you tried using `SHFileOperationW` instead of `SHFileOperationA`?

Comment: I'm not using either.  Are these file system objects?  At the moment I'm simply using the MkDir() function.

Comment: @Addikt I thought you were using it following Siddhart's answer to your previous question. Not sure about mkdir but I believe it has the same limitation.

Comment: Yes, MkDir() will fail if the resulting directory path will be longer than 260 characters.